# how to show notification like the one shown in the picture in ionic apps

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

how can I show notification ("Closed new tab") like the one shown in the picture in my ionic apps.

[image: chrome notification]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should share some code and show what you have done so far. There are couple of ways to do that one is using ionic toast you can read it on its github page and using it is pretty easy.
https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-toast

[demo](http://rajeshwarpatlolla.github.io/ionic-toast-demo/demo/#/tab/home)

Comment: ok...thanks...that will do.....i was just looking for some hint to start.